# How to send a condition to a method using lambda expression so that it is not yet evaluated?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, android-studio-2.0

I am trying send a condition statement (that has not been evaluated yet) as an argument to a method. I understand that in **java8**, the **lambda expression** is the way to do it (effectively putting the condition inside a function, and sending the function).

```
// simple method inside a utilities class 
//    that does assertions if global debug parameter is true

public class MyUtils
  {
    public  static void do_assertions( boolean argb , String args )
      {
        if( BuildConfig.pvb_debuggable )
          { assert argb  , args ;
          }
      }
  }
```

---

```
// somewhere within app where a development-phase assertion is needed

public class some_class
  { 
    public void some_method( )
      { 
        EditText lvo_editText = (EditText) findViewById( "the_id" ) ;

        //assert lvo_editText != null; 
        //   ... replace this with a call to do_assertions
        MyUtils.do_assertions( () -> { lvo_editText != null ; }  , "bad EditText" );
      } 
  }
```

I have tried many variations of this setup. I get different errors each time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there, you can change your signature to receive a [BooleanSupplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BooleanSupplier.html) which will evaluate the condition only when calling `getAsBoolean`.

Here a simple example :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A();
        test(() -> a != null && a.get());
    }

    static void test(BooleanSupplier condition) {
        condition.getAsBoolean();
    }

    static class A {
        boolean get(){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

If you go through this example in debug mode, you'll see that the condition `a != null && a.get()` is evaluated only when `condition.getAsBoolean()` is executed.

Applying this to your example, you would only need to change

```
void do_assertions( boolean argb , String args )
```

for

```
void do_assertions(BooleanSupplier argo_supplier , String args )
```

and then call `argo_supplier.getAsBoolean()` where you want to evaluate the condition (after checking `pvb_debuggable`).

Then your line

```
MyUtils.do_assertions( () -> lvo_editText != null  , "bad EditText" );
```

would compile properly (notice that I removed the unnecessary brackets).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard: It appears that the Android N Platform has support for Java 8 language features.

Comment: I think you're primarily right ... out of the box AS2 will handle the jdk1.8.*, but will NOT actually enable many of the actual java8 features (such as lambda) ... a couple options seem to exist: **1** --> _Enabling Java 8 Features and the Jack Toolchain_ (http://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html#configuration ) ... ... or **2** --> _Android N introduces support for Java 8 language features_ ( http://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html#configuration .. ... with that being said, your answer seems to be ... the answer ... thanks ...